# How to remove space between subcategory and category division?

Tags: javascript, css

```css
.category-list {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}

#subcat1 {
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-list" id="list-category">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';">First item</a>
    <div class="subcat" id="subcat1" style="display:none;" onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The two subcat division and category divison are getting a little space in between but I want to make them attached even when it is checked for responsive ness , if I make appropriate left index by hit and trial the space gets removed but it again comes when I check for responsive ness .
what can i use instead of position fixed to keep them both attached ! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What space are you talking about?

Comment: I have fixed the position of category-list and subcat1 due to which there is comes space in between them .I want to remove that space in between them

Comment: Why are you using `fixed` positioning. Just use `relative`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.category-list{
    width:20%;
    margin-left:50px;
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
    
   
}
#subcat1{
    width:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0
}
```

```html
  <div class="category-list" id="list-category">
                <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';" >First item</a>
                <div class="subcat" id="subcat1" style="display:none;" onmouseout="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'none';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('subcat1').style.display = 'block';">
                       <div class="list-group">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
                        </div>

                </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: almost but i have used bootstrap classes but when I check for responsiveness width of the category-list division changes and further the subcat division is getting overlapped

Comment: maybe i want to stop the width changes done by bootstrap on category-list division

Comment: Or fix the width on class .category-list based on different screen width using media queries.